# Convert a string to an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, infix-notation

If I have:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter an infixed expression:");
String expression = input.nextLine();

String[] tokens;
```

How do I scan the infix expression around spaces one token at a time, from left to right and put in into an array of strings? Here a `token` is defined as an operand, operator, or parentheses symbol.

Example: "3 + (9-2)" ==> tokens = [3][+][(][9][-][2][)]

Comment: String's `length()` and `charAt(int)` might be helpful. Don't use an array, use a list.

Comment: Will there always be spaces between the input characters? Your example suggests not, however you also mention "around spaces".

Answer (score 2):

```
String test = "13 + (9-2)";

List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+|\\(|\\)|\\+|\\*|-|/")
    .matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
  allMatches.add(m.group());
}
```

Can someone test this please?

Comment: This would surely split numbers though? `13` would become `[1][3]`.

Comment: @DuncanJones It would, I added some new code but I can't run it right now

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. It finds the numbers, but also a lot of empty strings.

Comment: Fixed it - you were just missing a `+` rather than a `*` in front of your digit matcher.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easiest to read the line into one string, and then split based on space. There is a handy string function `split` that does this for you.

```
String[] tokens = input.split("");
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to split around spaces.

Comment: Ahh you are right. Didn't see there wasn't a space between the `-` sign. Fixed it.

Comment: this results in: [3][ ][+][ ][(][9][-][2][)]. the indexes with spaces do not need to be there

Comment: Then remove whitespace beforehand. 

`input.replaceAll(" ", "").split("");`

Comment: -1. This will split operands if they are larger than one digit in length.

Comment: ahh you are correct. I had it splitting on whitespace, but there is no guarantee that there will be a space between characters, so what OP needs to do is  concatenate operands until he reaches a space or operand.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably overkill for your example, but in case it gets more complex, take a look at [JavaCC](https://java.net/projects/javacc), the Java Compiler Compiler. JavaCC allows you to create a parser in Java based on a grammar definition.

Be aware that it is not an easy tool to get started with. However, the grammar definition will be much easier to read than the corresponding regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

if tokens[] must be String you can use this

```
String ex="3 + (9-2)";
    String tokens[];
    StringTokenizer tok=new StringTokenizer(ex);
    String line="";
    while(tok.hasMoreTokens())line+=tok.nextToken();

    tokens=new String[line.length()];
    for(int i=1;i<line.length()+1;i++)tokens[i-1]=line.substring(i-1,i);
```

tokens can be a charArray so:

```
String ex="3 + (9-2)";
    char tokens[];
    StringTokenizer tok=new StringTokenizer(ex);
    String line="";
    while(tok.hasMoreTokens())line+=tok.nextToken();

    tokens=line.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This (IMHO elegant) single line of code works (tested):

```
String[] tokens = input.split("(?<=[^ ])(?<!\\B) *");
```

This regex also caters for input containing multiple character numbers (eg 123) which would be split into separate characters but for the negative look-behind for a non-word boundary `(?<!\\B)`.

The first look-behind `(?<=[^ ])` prevents an initial blank string split at start if input, and assures spaces are consumed.

The final part of the regex `" *"` assures spaces are consumed.